# How to trigger a anchor tag click event dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to trigger a already written click event for an anchor tag using JavaScript but it is not working. can any one please help me to do this

```
I have a anchor tag

<a id="memberid">Data Member</a>

<script>
   $("#memberid").click(function() {
       changebreadcrumb("Data Management");
   });
</script> 


i want to trigger above click event on load

i tried
   $("#memberid").click();

and 

   $("#memberid").trigger("click");


but did not work.
```

Comment: wrap your jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` block

Answer (score 1):

Place this at the end of your HTML before the closing `body` tag

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#memberid').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/axfqc6xc/)

Use jquery and check whether your dom is ready. It works fine.
 See the properties in the fiddle on its left side panel

```
  $("#memberid").click(function() {
      alert('clicked');
   });

  $("#memberid").trigger("click");
```

EDIT:
   [FINAL DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/axfqc6xc/1/)

If you want to triger click on pageload, use window.onload in javascript or jquery load method as i mentioned.

```
 $(window).load(function()
             {
               $("#memberid").trigger("click");
             });
```

Comment: Hi, what problem r u facing? Have u wrapped your code inside domready nd included jquery?

Comment: i have a click event in side which i have written what has to happen. now on load of the page i want to trigger that click event.

Answer (score 0):

If your click is not working then in that case....try on() function to trigger event

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#anchor_id").on( "click", function() {
        //your work
    });

});
```